# displaytag table together with other page buttons in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, displaytag

I'm writing an application in JSP and I'm trying to use display tag to display a table. I have a couple of buttons on the displayed page and the display tag table. The buttons work when I load up the application, but they stop redirecting to where they are supposed to once I click through the table pages. Here's the HTML code for the buttons:

```
<form action="index" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">        
    <h3>Enter formula:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="formula" id="formula"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Insert" class = "button">
</form>
<br />
<h3>Or press Delete or Modify:</h3>
<form action = "index" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class = "button">
</form>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<br />
<form action = "index" method = "post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="modify">
    <input type="submit" value="Modify" class = "button">
</form>
```

And here's the table html:

```
        <display:table name = "table" sort = "list" pagesize = "10" id = "table1" export = "true" >
        <display:column property = "id" title = "ID" group = "1" sortable = "true" headerClass = "sortable" />
        <display:column property = "formula" title = "FORMULA" group = "2" sortable = "true" headerClass = "sortable" />
        <display:setProperty name = "export.excel.filename" value = "FormulasTable.xls" />
        <display:setProperty name = "export.pdf.filename" value="FormulasTable.pdf" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="FormulasTable.csv" />
        <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
        </display:table>
```

Comment: index is a servlet ?

Comment: yes, I just modified it to servlet...